# Can I use getApplicationContext() object for synchronizing?

Tags: android, synchronized, thread-synchronization

When I have a small single block of code that should not get executed in parallel in my application (eg. when an Activity gets killed and restarted when the user turns the device), would it be possible to put it into a code block `synchronized` to the Application Context?

As far as I understood, this should work as long as the application context object stays the same over the full lifecycle of the app – but does it? I haven't found anything about its lifecycle.

```
synchronized (getApplicationContext()) {
    if (piCacheFileDoesNotExist() == true) {
        calculatePIandStoreToCacheFile();  // This is an example only...
    }
}
```

Would that example be a possible way (especially when the task is too small to create an extra `Service` for it) or would it be a bad idea because of anything I've missed?

Comment: Object lock will work as long `getApplicationContext()` returns a valid object . I don't understand why do u want to such thing ? Just create a `Object` for mutex why make things complicated ? Why hold a complex Object as Mutex just use an instance of Object class .

Comment: What's the point of using such object for synchronizing this? Use `Object()` if anything... but if this is Android, why not use a Coroutine tied to the Activity lifecycle? or the ViewModel of said activity?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini, for example when I turn the device and back, each time the current Activity gets ended and a new one starts, so I should not use those objects. What do you mean by `Object()`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're trying to solve the wrong problem with the wrong tools.

`syncrhonization`: This is often use to make some code "thread-safe-ish" by ensuring an "object" (any) can act as a gatekeeper. If you can guarantee that there's only one instance of some object, then multiple threads could ask said unique object "are you free so I can run this code?" if the answer is yes, then the code is executed on that thread, otherwise, the thread must wait until the object frees it. Think of a semaphore.

`synchronized(XXX) { ... }` is doing that. It ensures `...` is not executed until `XXX` says so. (note: this is an oversimplification).

It's often used like so:

```
private val lock = Object()


fun doSomething() {
   synchronized(lock) { ... }
}
```

This means the code `...` will only be executed by one thread at a time...

Now this has *nothing to do* with Android Lifecycle, App Lifecycle, and more specifically, Android Activity Lifecycle.

Your problem is an architecture problem. You have a UI (Activity) that can and will be destroyed by the Android OS at will (or when your users leave your app either explicitly or by performing a different action like turning the screen off).

You also have a block of code that -and I quote- "*should not get executed in parallel in my application*". Now this is a bit misleading. Do you not want this code to be run multiple times at the same time (in parallel, that is) or do you only want to run this code "once" in your app and never do it again until certain condition is fulfilled?

Depending on which case you need, the solutions may be different, but in all cases, the actual code that needs execution should not be part of an activity, because as we know, Activities are meant to be created and destroyed at all times. This then raises the question of: Where do I put this information that I want to persist for LONGER than what my activity does?

And here you have many options... from using a ViewModel (that can live a bit longer) to using a use-case/interactor/repository/etc. that can store this "information" in a more persistent way, and be able to provide it to the (new) activity when it is restored.

I suggest you spend some time reading about MVVM, Android Jetpack, Android Lifecyle, and, because your *block of code* appears to be "long work" you execute in a background thread, invest time in learning the basics of Kotlin Coroutines, LiveData and/or Flow/StateFlow, as they will make your modern Android life easier.

> when I turn the device and back, each time the current Activity gets ended and a new one starts

This means the data that would let the code/activity decide what to do, should not live in the activity, otherwise it would get lost when the inevitable Activity Destroy/Recreate happens. Think of this: You wouldn't store your car keys inside the car... would you? ;)

This is why ViewModels, Respositories, etc. can help you overcome this. In truth, you may or may not like the extra complexity, code, boiler-plate stuff, etc, that comes with this, but when you're developing an Android app, you have to abide by its idiosyncrasies (and bad decisions sometimes). Try telling an iOS dev that you don't want to use ViewControllers and that you're gonna build your own... they are going to scream at you: "Don't fight the framework!!!!!!!"...

Well, this is similar. Do your best to learn [the Android way](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/).